# How can I add individual settings to Android System settings?

Tags: android, android-source, android-settings

How can I add individual settings additional to *Android* system settings?

EDIT: As far as I understood I have to compile/build an own individual Android image from AOSP, with individual settings, and flash this android image onto that device. I searched how to customize/add some own settings to the system settings with AOSP - in vain.

I'll reward **helpful** links/tutorials/videos with where/how to make these changes in the AOSP to customize settings.

Comment: "I searched how to customize/add some own settings to the system settings with AOSP - in vain" -- [Settings is an app in the AOSP](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:packages/apps/Settings/). You would need to modify that app to change its UI to have what you want. "I'll reward helpful links/tutorials/videos with where/how to make these changes in the AOSP to customize settings." -- c'mon, you have nearly 2K rep. You should know that asking for off-site resources is considered off-topic here.

Comment: I probably get those 2k rep by asking noob questions, which were highly demanded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I add individual settings additional to *Android* system settings?

By building a [custom Android image](https://source.android.com/) and changing the settings app at [packages/apps/Settings/src/com/android/settings](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:packages/apps/Settings/src/com/android/settings/).

Comment: then I have to build that image and flash it to the devices ROM?

Comment: @Ralf Wickum, yes... Sorry for the 3-years-late reply :)